# How to set up Win32 tooltips control with dynamic unicode text?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, tooltip

I am having some trouble provding a Win32 tooltips control with dynamic text in unicode format. I use the following code to set up the control:

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
icc.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
icc.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&icc);

HWND hwnd_tip = CreateWindowExW(0, TOOLTIPS_CLASSW, NULL, 
  WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP, 
  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
  NULL, NULL, hinst, NULL
);
SetWindowPos(hwnd_tip, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

TOOLINFOW ti;
memset(&ti, 0, sizeof(TOOLINFOW));
ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFOW);
ti.hwnd = hwnd_main;
ti.uId = (UINT) hwnd_control;
ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
ti.lpszText = L"This tip is shown correctly, including unicode characters.";
SendMessageW(hwnd_tip, TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, (LPARAM) &ti);
```

This works fine as long as I provide the tooltip text in `ti.lpszText`. However, I want the text to be dynamic, so instead I set `ti.lpszText` to `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACKW` and handle the callback in my WindowProc(), like this:

```
...
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
  NMHDR *nm = (NMHDR *) lParam;
  switch (nm->code)
  {
    case TTN_GETDISPINFOW:
    {
      static std::wstring tip_string = L"Some random unicode string.";
      NMTTDISPINFOW *nmtdi = (NMTTDISPINFOW *) lParam;              
      nmtdi->lpszText = (LPWSTR) tip_string.c_str();
    }
    break;
  }
}
break;
...
```

Which does not work, as I never receive the `TTN_GETDISPINOW` message. (Note: It works if I handle `TTN_GETDISPINFO` instead and use `NMTTDISPINFO` to provide a char array, but then no unicode support...)

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong in my setup or message handling here? Any suggestions on how to do it properly?

**Update** 
Also note that my project is not compiled in unicoe mode (i.e. _UNICODE is not defined and the project is set to use multi-byte character set). This is intentional and I would like to keep it like that as, I have no desire to rewrite the entire application to be unicode-aware (at least not yet). Since the _UNICODE define is used to select *W versions of various functions and data structures I was hoping I could achieve the same result by using these explicitly in my code, as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the Robert Scott link. I found a way to solve it now.

**In short, the trick was to make sure the receiving window was a unicode window and register a unicode window procedure for it.**

The problem was that I did not have a unicode `WindowProc()` for my parent window handling the `TTN_GETDISPINFOW` notification message. Since this window (class) was created with `RegisterClassEx()/CreateWindowEx() and not RegisterClassExW()/CreateWindowExW(), it did not have registered window procedure for unicode messages.`

To get around the problem I changed `ti.hwnd` from `hwnd_main` to `hwnd_control` when sending TTM_ADDTOOLW, resulting in the control's window procedure receving the notifications instead of its parent.  In order to intercept the unicode events now sent to the control's window procedure, I subclassed it using SetWindowLongW(hwnd_control, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG) NewControlWndProc).

Note that hwnd_control is a standard "LISTBOX" window created with CreateWindowExW() and is therefore unicode-aware, since all buildt-in Windows classes are automatically registered in both unicode and ANSI version by the system.

Comment: Quite likely the correct solution, I was about to post the same. Windows internally is Unicode, but will marshall API arguments when running an MBCS (aka ANSI aka Windows95) application.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you get the TTN_GETDISPINFO notification code but not TTN_GETDISPINFOW indicates that your project is setup to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".
Check the projects property pages: "Configuration Properties" -> "General" -> "Character Set"

This property should be set to "Use Unicode Character Set".

Answer (score 1):

Is your whole application using unicode? Else you might read this ["Microsoft article"](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/cs.htm). Especially the *"Twelve steps to Unicode-enabling"* section.

Or try like this guy did

[Robert Scott Unicode Tooltips](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer/msg/1c7a4723cb01a6f4)